# Slow LAN Networks Speeds With Wireless Bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, bridge

I am having an internal networking issue I need help with.

Layout. AC Router A with all standard router functions enabled. 
AC Router B is connected wirelessly to AC Router A via a wireless bridge. All routing functions are disabled. 
Computer A is hardwired to AC Router B - external speed tests are as expected.

The problem is when Computer B is wirelessly connected to AC Router A - LAN transfer speeds with Computer A are terrible (<10 MB/s). If I connect Computer B wirelessly to AC Router B, I achieve typical AC transfer rates with Computer A.

Further, if I run a VPN on Computer A connected to wireless bridge AC Router B, external network speeds are cut by 75%. If I connect Computer A to AC Router A, VPN speeds are on-par with expected internet speeds (i.e., VPN not throttling).

Any quick ideas or thoughts about these two issues?

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you mean by "a wireless bridge"? Is it WDS? AirMAX? Or some kind of fake bridging that connects to the access point as a regular client? Is the wireless bridge a physically separate device from the two routers? (If not, 10MB/s for 6 wireless hops that all have to be on the same channel is not bad.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you have an implicit bad assumption that the two routers are communicating to each other at the high end of 802.11ac rates. Depending on how you configured things, the routers may be doing their wireless bridging over 2.4GHz at 802.11n rates. Even if they *are* using their 5GHz radios for the bridge link, they may be so far apart that they're falling back to 802.11n or 802.11a rates.